# Cant combine two selects together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing timestamps and the direction(In/Out)

```
CASE 1:in,  2016-07-06 08:00:00, I
CASE 1:out, 2016-07-06 17:00:00, O
CASE 2:in,  2016-07-12 08:00:00, I
CASE 2:out, 2016-07-13 17:00:00, O
CASE 3:in,  2016-07-14 08:00:00, I
CASE 3:out, 2016-07-18 17:00:00, O
```

I would like to create a select that shows me all rows that have been In at 03am every morning. It should also show me all days of the months it was in.

As you see from the example, Case 1 should not be returned because it was not In at 03:00 am.

So far i have created a select statement to check for a particular day:

```
Select t.* from 
     (SELECT * FROM movement 
      where scan_date < '2016-07-06 03:00:00' 
      order by scan_date desc limit 1) t
WHERE t.direction='I';
```

So far so good. I would now like to check that against the whole month.
For simplicity i have created a table with all 3am entiries for the whole month:

```
Select day from month
```

returns

2017-07-01 03:00:00 
...and so on...

For some reason i am not able to combine these two selects. 
I cant use the second table in the < clause because it tells me that it returns more then one row.

The problem sounds simple but didnt find a solution so far.
If anybody has any ideas i would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Could you eliminate some uncertainty by showing us sample input and output?

Comment: I have to specify a little bit more. I have updated a sample table. An out is always following after an In. An In can be a couple of days before an Out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated problem statement, the following should get you started:

```
SELECT
  check_time
  , CAST(LEFT(checktime_direction, 19) AS DATETIME) scan_time
  , RIGHT(checktime_direction, 1) direction
FROM (
  SELECT
    CP.p check_time
    , (SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(scan_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), direction)
       FROM Movement
       WHERE scan_date = (SELECT MAX(scan_date)
                          FROM Movement
                          WHERE scan_date <= CP.p
                         )
      ) checktime_direction
  FROM Checkpoint CP
) T
WHERE RIGHT(checktime_direction, 1) = 'I'
ORDER BY check_time
;
```

For your sample data it returns:

```
|             check_time |              scan_time | direction |
|------------------------|------------------------|-----------|
| July, 13 2016 03:00:00 | July, 12 2016 08:00:00 |         I |
| July, 15 2016 03:00:00 | July, 14 2016 08:00:00 |         I |
| July, 16 2016 03:00:00 | July, 14 2016 08:00:00 |         I |
| July, 17 2016 03:00:00 | July, 14 2016 08:00:00 |         I |
| July, 18 2016 03:00:00 | July, 14 2016 08:00:00 |         I |
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94b43/1).
NB: The helper table has been called **Checkpoint** rather than **month** as the latter is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

### How does it work?

The overall solution approach is to use a [correlated (or "synchronized") subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).
Generally speaking, the inner query pulls up the most recent direction change for the respective outer checkpoint. This (intermediate) result set in turn is filtered to retain just the "I" records.

In detail:

```
SELECT
  CP.p check_time
  [...]
FROM Checkpoint CP
```

is the outer query, setting the scene. (In the context of the mentioned synch, that is. To get the wanted result, this "outer" query is wrapped itself. - But this involves no correlating, just filtering.)

```
    SELECT MAX(scan_date)
    FROM Movement
    WHERE scan_date <= CP.p
```

is linked to it via **CP.p**.
As you asked for both **scan_date** and **direction** to be pulled up for your final result, another level is introduced in between the two:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(scan_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), direction)
  FROM Movement
  WHERE scan_date = ([...]
                    )
```

This query gets two columns - but its output needs to fit into a single column in the outer query. Therefore, the two columns are combined into one - in a way ensuring correct disassembly later on.

From here, all that's left to do, is to get rid of the "O" records (and put the remaining one's into the correct order). Well - the earlier combined into one column **scan_time** and **direction** are waiting to get separated (and the former to be returned to `DATETIME`):

```
SELECT
  check_time
  , CAST(LEFT(checktime_direction, 19) AS DATETIME) scan_time
  , RIGHT(checktime_direction, 1) direction
FROM (
  [...]
) T
WHERE RIGHT(checktime_direction, 1) = 'I'
ORDER BY check_time
;
```

<sup>You might want to use the Fiddle, break apart the query, play with the pieces, and watch the show...

Mind the pair of round brackets / parentheses surrounding each sub-select. These are required by the SQL syntax.</sup>

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Holy crap has that select been found on that spaceship in roswell? Beside that i have no clue how it works i have to say it works. Thanks your the best

Comment: @user2316219 Sorry to disappoint: No Roswell relation. ;-) Handcrafted, made right to your order. I'll add a few words of explanation on its workings later. - Actually: The helper table should not really be necessary. But I didn't have the time/urge to include this into this excercise whilst you were waiting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select movement.* 
from month
inner join movement ON scan_date < month.day AND direction='I'
GROUP BY month.day
ORDER BY movement.scan_date DESC
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Sorry i was not very specific at the table. You have to consider the Out to know that it was In. So you have to check againt a time period that can span over multipe days.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, extract(day from scan_date) as days_of_month
from movement where extract(hour from scan_date) = 3
and direction='I'
order by scan_date desc;
```

If you need anything more then please explain them with table structure.

Comment: Sorry i was not very specific at the table. I am looking for records that have been in at 3 am but not at the exact time.